# Draw in mspaint programmatically

Tags: gdi

if you get the window handle, would there be any possible way to draw something using GDI functions or send paint data to window?

Comment: What language are using? What do you want to draw? Can you afford to just simulate mouse events and motions? If so, gdi may be an overkill. You could use autoit script or something similar.

Comment: I'm using C and I want to draw something by setting pixel of data

Comment: If you're going to draw into a bitmap in your code, why use MSPAINT at all? Why not just load the bitmap into memory, draw into it, and then save the result?

Comment: I agree with Jerry.  Using MSPaint in this situation just sounds ridiculous, unless you have a very good reason to go this route.

Comment: I know but how would you possibly do that?